# Why did Einstein get credit for formulating the theory of special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, history

See [*The Principle of Relativity*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Mathematical_Physics#The_Principle_of_Relativity.) here: [*The Principles of Mathematical Physics*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Mathematical_Physics). This was written by Poincaré in 1904, a year before Einstein published his [theory of relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity).

It appears from this and other writings of Poincaré that Poincaré discovered the theory of [special relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_special_relativity) before Einstein. So why does Einstein get the credit?

Comment: Also, it is worth pointing out that Lorentz contraction is called _Lorentz contraction_ for a reason. Lorentz did some good work on this aspect of relativity, but did not understand the result. It was Einstein that gave these finding physical meaning/enterpretation and this was recognised by Lorentz. @RonMaimon is 100% right with what he is saying here...

Comment: @Killercam: But Poincare differed from Lorentz in this regard, in that Poincare really believed the contraction was of no physical significance, and that any two frames are truly equivalent in every respect. In this sense he certainly knew the principle of relativity. His screw-ups are in the details of mechanics and electromagnetism, and the only real one I found is not formulating E=mc^2, something he fixes after Einstein's work.

Comment: I find no fault in anything you are saying. You know your stuff... All the best.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Poincaré was confused on several points. (See the discussion on Wikipedia regarding "mass energy equivalence".) He could never get the mechanical relations straight, since he could not figure out that $E=mc^2$. Einstein followed Poincaré closely in 1905, he was aware of Poincaré's work, but he derived the theory simply as a geometric symmetry, and made a complete system.

Einstein did share the credit with Lorentz and Poincaré for special relativity for a while, probably one reason his Nobel prize did not mention relativity. Pauli in the Encyclopædia Britannica article famously credits Einstein alone for formulating the relativity principle, as did Lorentz. Poincaré was less accomodating. He would say "Einstein just assumed that which we were all trying to prove" (namely the principle of relativity). (I could not find a reference for this, and I might be misquoting. It is important, because it shows whether Poincaré was still trying to get relativity from Maxwell's equations, rather than making a new postulate—I don't know.)

Special relativity was ripe for discovery in 1905, and Einstein wasn't the only one who could have done it, although he did do it best, and only he got the $E=mc^2$ without which nothing makes sense. Poincaré and Lorentz deserve at least 50% of the credit (as Einstein himself accepted), and Poincaré has most of the modern theory, so Einstein's sole completely original contribution is $E=mc^2$.

Comment: I'd say he showed that the Lorentz force equation comes from Maxwell's equations, rather than having to be added on. $E =mc^2$ wasn't proved adequately in his first paper, hence the title in the form of a question: "Does the Inertia of a Body Depend upon its Energy-Content?"

Comment: I just wanted to add some detail about Lorentz in particular.  I've read that he actually misinterpreted his own transformations as applying to the Ether (in fact I think he derived them purposely to describe how the ether "reacts" in such a way as to be in accord with experiments (Michelson-Morley?).  So Einstein at the very least gets credit for being the first to correctly interpret the equations and do away with the Ether concept.

Comment: Actually it was Lorentz who said that Einstein just postulated what had previously been proved. Everyone agrees that Poincare formulated and published the relativity principle well before Einstein.

Comment: @Roger: I remember that Poincare said it negatively, perhaps Lorentz said it positively. The problem with Poincare's work is his renounciation that energy carries inertia from emitter to absorber, and the resulting rest frame that the separation "mass" and "energy" entails. This appears in 1904, while not in earlier 1900 work (he probably wasn't confident at either point) and this gets sorted out by Einstein. The issue is important, Poincare did a center of mass theorem that fails (as he noted) if radiation doesn't carry inertia between emitter and absorber.

Comment: @tachyonicbrane: I agree for Lorentz, not so much for Poincare. Poincare wanted a manifestly invariant formulation, he just stumbled on some details. It is perhaps for this reason that Lorentz accepts Einstein as the founder of relativity, while Poincare is less accomodating of the upstart. Also, Einstein read Poincare, not Lorentz, of this we can be sure, because he goes through the work "breathlessly" (his words, at least in German) in his private correspondence of 1904.

Comment: @LarryHarson: Einstein demonstrated that E=mc^2 completely fine in his first paper. The only reason the paper has a question mark is because it is such a radical hypothesis, and he didn't yet show it fixes the center of mass theorem and the conservation laws (it does, and he explicitly shows this in 1906, this time with due reference to Poincare). Max Planck was the first to claim that Einstein's 1905 argument for E=mc^2 is deficient, and he is not right on this.

Comment: @RonMaimon you told someone in a previous post you've never read the original paper and don't want to!

Comment: @LarryHarson: I did read it, a long time ago, I didn't work out the detailed calculations (until that question came up, then I went through it line by line, and it was annoying, because I learned nothing new), I just looked at it and said "oh, that's the setup", and did it my own way, then did spot-checks to see it matched Einstein, and then moved on. I understand the paper completely, I just don't like his notation and conventions, as they are obsolete.

Answer (score 17):

I think the quote Maimon gives of Poincare, "Einstein just assumes that which we were all trying to prove." highlights exactly why Poincare did not discover anything like special relativity. Poincare was looking for a "mechanical" explanation of why the speed of light "appeared" constant in all reference frames. In other words, Poincare did not even believe in relativity in the Einsteinian sense. He believed that there was a preferred frame at a fundamental level.

What Einstein did was to raise the "problem" of the speed of light appearing constant in all reference frames to the level of a postulate. This is what Poincare means when he says "Einstein just assumes that which we were all trying to prove". I think Poincare didn't really understand what Einstein had done -- space and time were fundamentally woven together in Einstein's theory. In Poincare-Lorentz's theory, space and time are separate, but only appear to be woven together -- there is a preferred frame where simultaneity of spacially separated events is absolute.

I would also like to add -- and this part is just speculation -- that I believe we would still not have special relativity today if it hadn't been for Einstein. I believe we would still be working in the framework of Lorentz-Poincare, where Lorentz Invariance is achieved at an observational level, but fundamentally the theory has a preferred reference frame.

Comment: Does it really matter if his theory has a preferred reference time, as long as the theory works (makes correct predictions)?

Comment: @CraigFeinstein Does it really matter if burning materials give off phlogiston, and it's buildup suppresses combustion as long as it correctly predicts that a burning splint placed inside a small sealed container will rapidly be extinguished?

Comment: Well, your question was why did Einstein get credit for relativity. Relativity says there are no preferred frames. Einstein removed the preferred frame from the theories of Lorentz and Poincare, so he is credited with relativity. You are right that Lorentz's theory had the same equations -- they are called the Lorentz transformations for a reason, however it is not a theory of relativity.

Comment: It is also of interest to mention now that the theory of Lorentz and Poincare is very much akin to the current formulation of quantum mechanics. In quantum mechanics there is a fundamental preferred frame in which one can describe the causal sequence in entanglement, however the theory is completely Lorentz invariant at an observational level. The fact that almost no serious physicists realize this is precisely why I believe nobody would have ever discovered relativity without Einstein.

Comment: Another way of phrasing my question is, "What does Einstein's special theory of relativity correctly predict that Poincare's relativity does not correctly predict?"

Comment: @CraigFeinstein: The E=mc^2 requires full relativity, as Poincare never made it there, at least not before Einstein showed the way. This is discussed in the talk page of mass-energy equivalence on Wikipedia--- it's what makes Einstein E=mc^2 paper so important.

Comment: @user7348: this is not 100% accurate--- you can formulate quantum mechanics as a path integral (or as S-matrix) and either way allows a Lorentz invariant formulation. Field theory is Lorentz invariant in path integral, and string theory is Lorentz invariant in S-matrix sense (and in worldsheet path-integral sense, at least in the appropriate formalism).

Comment: @ Maimon, I've never said quantum mechanics didn't have Lorentz Invariant equations.  The situation is very similar to 1905 when Einstein wrote, 'There are assymetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena'.  My point is that Bell showed that there has to be information exchanged between entangled particles.  Now, the current description has a cause and effect relationship varying depending on your choice of frame. If you want to have a single causal description, then you have to single out a preferred frame.  THERE IS A WAY OUT! I can show you, if you'd like my email?

Comment: @user7348: Post it publically here--- as a question with the title "Is this a way out?" and I'll read it. I have no problem with many-worlds, and I don't see the collapse as a real thing, so I don't see any problem reconciling quantum mechanics in flat or AdS spaces with relativity. Your way out is probably wrong, with 90% confidence, unless it is based on holographic hidden variables.

Comment: @user7348: You have it backwards about who combined space and time. Poincare used spacetime 4-vectors in 1905, with the index running from 1 to 4. Einstein had nothing like that in his famous paper. Minkowski made that approach famous, so we did get special relativity without Einstein.

Comment: @Roger: Sorry, I didn't read Poincare directly, I read the references Einstein makes to Poincare's papers in 1906. I am sure Poincare had a geometric and good understanding of Lorentz covariance, what he didn't have is the physical confidence to state the energy is mass, and he actually states the opposite at one point ("the waves are not carrying mass, they are carrying energy"), and this means his center of mass theorem fails, and center of mass conservation is violated in his reasoning.

Comment: @Roger & Maimon: Einstein was the only one who appreciated the length contraction, the time dilation, the relativity of simultaneity. Lorentz didn't even like what Einstein had done, only warming up to his ideas after general relativity was so enormously successful, and even then he didn't fully embrace Einstein's ideas. For Lorentz, and Poincare, there IS absolute simultaneity, frames only appear to be equivalent.

Comment: @ Maimon: Forget it, you wouldn't understand the ideas, or appreciate them anyhow.

Comment: @user7348: There is no chance that I would fail to understand them, after some careful study. I would only not appreciate them if they are wrong, which they probably are.

Comment: @user7348: True for Lorentz, not clear for Poincare.

Comment: @Maimon: Be sure, they are not my ideas. As far as Poincare goes, he was extremely close to getting special relativity. He even speculated that simultaneity may be relative. Ultimately, he did not ever come to the two fundamental principles of relativity which Einstein clearly states in his theory. I can't be sure, but I doubt we'd have it today without Einstein.

Comment: @user7348: Lorentz lectured on relativity at Columbia U. in 1906, and those lectures were eventually published. Lorentz described Einstein's contributions and accepted relativity. When you say that "frames only appear to be equivalent", you are doing some weird philosophical hair-splitting that is not grounded in anything that Lorentz, Poincare, or Einstein actually said. What are you saying -- that Lorentz and Poincare had all the formulas but did not "appreciate" them somehow?

Comment: @Roger: Yes, I am exactly saying that Lorentz and Poincare had the formulas but didn't appreciate them. That's exactly what I'm saying. Please read the wikipedia article on Lorentz, the quote from 1910, he clearly believes in the ether, but the whole point of relativity is that there is no preferred coordinate system.

Comment: @Roger: I don't care about philosophy, so if someone says "there is an undetectable ether" and someone else says "no, it's relativity, there's no ether", but the predictions are the same, I don't care. But Lorentz and Poincare, because of their failure of philosophy, made crucial mistakes in certain predictions, in particular the CM theorem for systems with EM fields failed for Poincare, and Lorentz never even got so far. Only Einstein had the full system, but Poincare came so close that it is ridiculous to deny him half the credit.

Comment: @Maimon, that's a fair position... I would like to point out that while many people made contributions towards special relativity, Minkowski for example realized special relativity as a geometric revision of space and time into space-time... Einstein alone is credited with the entire development of General Relativity... I think it is very unlikely that anybody would have ever thought of general relativity without Einstein.

Comment: @RonMaimon Have a look at this firsthand account of how little Poincare actually grasped of the new way of looking at the world. http://mathpages.com/home/kmath630/kmath630.htm  He played with the ideas but he couldn't accept where they brought him. If he wasn't able to make that leap even after reading Einstein's paper, I don't think you can credit him with half of special relativity.

Comment: @user7348: Only some antisemitic crackpot sources dispute that.

Comment: @James: That stuff is hearsay, Poincare only wanted to keep Newton's mechanics as much as possible, and he had a hard time with E=mc^2, but he was the one in 1902 who actually modified Newton first, and was led to the realization that the center of mass theorem would work if radiation carried mass between emitter and absorber. But he just couldn't make the leap. The mathematics and the principles Poincare states in 1902 are 50% of the theory though. It's similar with Einstein and QM: Einstein got 40% of the way to Schrodinger's equation in 1924, but Schrodinger deserves the bulk of the credit.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Poincare did make the leap to the spacetime geometry interpretation of special relativity, as shown by publishing the 5 points below in 1905. Einstein had none of those 5 points until several years later. If you disagree, please post the quotes from Einstein.

Answer (score 8):

Poincare introduced in 1905 the spacetime geometry as we know it today. I say this because (1) he combined space and time into a 4-dimensional spacetime, (2) he defined the metric, now known as the Minkowski metric, (3) he formulated the Lorentz group (and not any Galilean group) as the symmetries of spacetime, (4) his relativity was a spacetime theory that was applicable to electromagnetism as well as any other forces, and (5) he proved that the electromagnetism equations were covariant with respect to the spacetime geometry. These 5 concepts form the core of what modern textbooks teach as relativistic geometry. Poincare had them all in 1905, and Einstein had none of them.

Comment: That's not true--- Einstein had the electrodynamic transformations in 1905, and the correct energy density and momentum density expressions, and the right relation between mass and energy. Poicare had all but the last, and this got him confused on several important points.

Comment: Yes, Einstein had the electrodynamic transformations in 1905. So did Lorentz in 1904. But they did not have those 5 points that summarize the spacetime geometry.

Comment: I meant Einstein had all 5 points, minus the Minkowski metric, but he had the interval relation somewhere in his paper. Poincare was annoyingly wrong on several points, but he and Lorentz certainly deserve 50% of the credit, just Einstein deserves the other 50%.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to note that Poincaré did not have spacetime geometry before Minkowski because: A) he did not define it through non-galilean relativity, B) Poincaré did not express particle motion in terms of a worldline, or define proper time as a worldline parameter. So inasmuch as spacetime geometry includes worldlines and proper time, Poincaré did not discover spacetime geometry.

Comment: This is not right--- Poincare had worldlines (as did everybody), and he defined "proper time" at least along a moving observer's axis, and it's no stretch from this to worldline proper time. Poincare deserves 50% of the credit for SR, it's just that he didn't finish it.

Comment: Actually, in 1905 and prior, his work on space-time vectors showed no expression at all of motion with regards to wordline nor proper time as a worldline parameter. He might have included it more formally after -07, albeit in his lectures (his famous London lecture for instance) he noted that Minkowski spacetime was the new one and his was merely galilean space and time with an added 4-d vector. Naturally the formulation of 4-d vectors are interesting but for the meat of SR not strictly necessary. Poincaré deserves at least 50% credit for SR, I agree.´

Comment: Also, in the above mentioned lecture, as a curiosa; Poincaré noted a preference *against* using Minkowski spacetime. Another curiosa, Moskowzki sat in the audience at his Berlin lecture where Poincaré had talked about Einstein's work both in the positive and negative. The speech-transcript does not include any explicit mention of Einstein by name though, so we are left to assume he did a bit of adlib when talking about Einstein specifically. From Moskowzkis impression, it seems Poincaré did indeed regard Einstein's work as not only different to his but... too revolutionary and daring.

Comment: Looking at comments on what Einstein had that Poincaré didn't have, beyond the mass-equivalence stroke; where Einstein argued that a light pulse which is spherical in *one* inertial frame, is spherical in *every* inertial frame. According to Poincaré, a light pulse that is spherical in the above mentioned privileged frame is an *elongated ellipsoid* in every other inertial frame. The difference in description is due to that fact that Einstein recognized the relativity of spatio-temporal coordinates, when Poincaré did not. And, the aberration constant, Poincaré didn't derive it, Einstein did.

Comment: It is possible to be a little less charitable when reading historical works. I don't dispute what you say, and this is why Einstein deserves the other 50% of the credit, but it is possible that Poincare was just following convention and describing things in one reference frame for mathematical convenience, not because he actually believed there was a preferred frame. I am not sure.

Comment: Indeed it is not, as you said, easy to assume exactly what was ment. Poincaré was, on a side note, big on conventionalism in general, almost to the point where most pursuits were based on conventions in his mind. According to Schlick (1921), who used to have been a defender of Poincaré's conventionalism, noted how Einstein denied that a lot of the formulations and tools used to derive them were strictly conventions, and this might be why Schlick later changed views as relativity (GR especially) was gradually shown to be validated by experiment after experiment.

Comment: Poincare certainly did define the spacetime geometry in terms of non-Galilean relativity. He explicitly used the Lorentz group as the transformation group. The reason we have the term "Lorentz group" is because Poincare introduced it in his 1905 paper. Poincare also had the metric and other core geometry features, as noted below, and Einstein did not.

Comment: Yet still Poincaré did not define spacetime geometry in terms of non-galilean relativity. That Poincaré introduced his group and Lorentz group is irrelevant to that fact. And like I said before, talking about space-time geometry, it was Minkowski who did his "own" formulation of it, in turn based on a previous reformulation he did which again in turn was based on the few relativistic notes Poincaré had made on 4-d vectors. Minkowski's spacetime, unlike Poincaré's, is non-galilean, and this was one of the BIG issues he had with Minkowskis work. And, one works with GR, one doesn't. Guess which?

Answer (score 3):

From what I've been told by my mentors there were a few things that happened.

- Poincare was extremely generous person, he routinely attributed his contributions to others left and right. For instance, he contributed the transformations to Lorentz, while Lorentz himself admitted he didn't do them in the form in which Poincare presented them, and didn't see their value at the time. That was one factor why Poincare did not insist on attribution to his work from Einsten.
- Einstein was told by his mentor Minkowsky about Poincare's work, which included pretty much everything on special and general relativity, including $mc^2$ which was derived by Poincare. Minkowsky was friends with Poincare, and theyt had a lot of private communication with stuff which was not published. Einstein took everything that Poincare did, and did not refer to him until way-way later, many years later. He then pretended that he forgot. Yes, of course. Rightfully, he did not get Nobel for relativity work, because at the time everyone knew what was going. Minkowsky spoke with Poincare on the subject, and the latter did not want to complain.
- There was some anymosity between German and French, and also physicists vs. mathematicians kind. So Planck and other German dudes kept promoting EInstein's work, and consistently ignored Poincare's. For instance, there are myths that somehow Poincare did not do general relativity (false), or that he wanted ether (false) etc. It sort of worked, the general population thinks Einstein did it all, but all physicist know that something's not right with this business.

You can find a few historical researches on the subject out there, like [this one](http://web.ihep.su/library/pubs/tconf05/ps/c5-1.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

To begin, let's start with a very apropos anecdote from Lorentz himself. At a conference on the Michelson–Morley experiment in 1927 at which Lorentz and Michelson were present, Michelson suggested that Lorentz was the initiator of the theory of relativity. Lorentz then replied: "I considered my time transformation only as a heuristic working hypothesis. So the theory of relativity is really solely Einstein's work. And there can be no doubt that he would have conceived it even if the work of all his predecessors in the theory of this field had not been done at all. His work is in this respect independent of the previous theories." Lorentz, replying to Michelson at the Solvay Conference.

Poincaré never fully understood the mechanical relations of the coordinate system; because of this, he never correctly derived E=Mc2. Einstein knew of some of Lorentz and Poincare's work - though it is clear he did not have access to *all* of their principal works. He began with a simple geometric symmetry operating on one, and only one, guiding postulate, and from there derived a complete system from first principles: the speed of light is invariant and is the same for all frames of reference.

In addition to Lorentz and Poincarém, Fitzgerald and Maxwell also deserve credit for their contributions as well. The great physicist Wolfgang Pauli, the great historian of science T.S. Kuhn, and even Lorentz himself, famously credit Einstein alone for formulating the relativity principle. Poincaré was less generous, but that is probably because he never fully understood Einsteinian relativity and was mired in the Galilean conception of relativity in which there is always a privileged frame of reference. Poincaré was still trying to get relativity from Maxwell's equations, rather than derive the coordinate systems from the invariance of light speed. This is a huge difference. See below.

Special relativity was being groomed for discovery in 1905, but it was Einstein, and Einstein alone, who derived a complete system from first principles (using one fundamental postulate) and only he correctly derived E=mc2 from said postulate. Without his derivation of E=Mc2, the system falls apart. Poincaré, Lorentz, Fitzgerald, and Maxwell deserve 50% of the credit (as Einstein himself accepted), but that's like splitting hairs and pointing out that Descartes and Fermat deserve 70% of the credit for calculus when Newton and Leibniz were the first to integrate the various derivations of analytical geometry.

Lorentz actually misinterpreted his own transformations as applying to the Ether (in fact I think he derived them purposely to describe how the ether "reacts" in such a way as to be in accord with experiments (Michelson-Morley). So Einstein gets credit for being the first to correctly interpret the equations and do away with the Ether concept. Both Poincare and Lorentz believed in the aether - a non-trivial fact - which represents a privileged frame of reference (Galilean relativity) as opposed to a coordinate system that has NO preferred reference frame (Einsteinian relativity).

Einstein derived E=MC2 from first principle, notably that energy carries inertia from emitter to absorber, and the resulting rest frame that the separation "mass" and "energy" entails. This derivation of E=mC2 as a consequence of special relativity is epistemically critical to Dirac's later reconciliation of special relativity and quantum mechanics.

Einstein had the correct electrodynamic transformations in 1905, and the correct energy density and momentum density expressions, and the right relation between mass and energy. Poincare had all but the last, and this got him confused on several important points. Poincaré did not have spacetime geometry before Minkowski because: A) he did not define it through non-galilean relativity, B) Poincaré did not express particle motion in terms of a worldline, or define proper time as a worldline parameter. So inasmuch as spacetime geometry includes worldlines and proper time, Poincaré did not discover spacetime geometry. Einstein's complete systemization of the Lorentz transformations and the second order transformations essentially wove space and time together in a way that is non-Galilean (Poincare never got that far). Minkowski, took Einstein's interval relation and mathematized it in 4-d vectors (but again, it was already implied in Einstein's 1905 paper).

To borrow from Ron Maimon and Jonathan Svarttorn's dialogue, Poincaré noted a preference against using Minkowski spacetime. Another curiosa, Moskowzki sat in the audience at his Berlin lecture where Poincaré had talked about Einstein's work both in the positive and negative. The speech-transcript does not include any explicit mention of Einstein by name though, so we are left to assume he did a bit of adlib when talking about Einstein specifically. From Moskowzkis impression, it seems Poincaré did indeed regard Einstein's work as not only different to his but... too revolutionary and daring. See link: http://mathpages.com/home/kmath630/kmath630.htm

Einstein argued that a light pulse which is spherical in one inertial frame, is spherical in every inertial frame. According to Poincaré, a light pulse that is spherical in the above mentioned privileged frame is an elongated ellipsoid in every other inertial frame. The difference in description is due to that fact that Einstein recognized the relativity of spatio-temporal coordinates, when Poincaré did not. And, the aberration constant, Poincaré didn't derive it, Einstein did.

Although Poincaré understood independently of Einstein how the Lorentz transformations give rise to non-Galilean transformation rules for velocities (indeed Poincaré derived the correct relativistic rules), it is clear that he did not have a full appreciation of the modern operational significance attached to coordinate transformations. He did not seem to understand the role played by the second-order terms in the transformation. Compared with the cases of Lorentz and Larmor, it is clear that Poincaré did not fully understand either length contraction or time dilation to be a consequence of the coordinate transformation. What Poincaré was holding out for was no less than a new theory of ether and matter - something far more far-fetched than what appeared in Einstein's 1905 relativity paper. Einstein's rejection of the aether is important, but is not the pivotal difference between his conception of relativity and Lorentz/Poincare conceptions. Why? Because it is always possible to add for whatever reason the notion of a privileged frame to special relativity, as long as one accepts that it will remain unobservable. However, in addition to the examples given above, there are other new features in Einstein's work:

*The full meaning of relativistic kinematics was simply not properly understood before Einstein. Nor was the 'theory of relativity' as Einstein articulated it in 1905 anticipated even in its programmatic form. It is impossible to understand the full implications of Einstein's discovery of special relativity without taking on board the impacts of the quantum in physics (see Paul Dirac). In respect to the conventional nature of distant simultaneity, Einstein was doing little more than expanding on a theme that Poincaré had already introduced. Where Einstein goes well beyond the great mathematician is in his treatment of the coordinate transformations. In particular, the extraction of the phenomena of length contraction and time dilation directly from the Lorentz transformations in section 4 of the 1905 paper is completely original. The genius of Einstein's 1905 paper is that the modern, dynamical interpretation of special relativity - as opposed to the kinematical approach of Einstein's 1905 paper - is ALREADY contained in Einstein's 1905-paper "masqueraded in the language of kinematics" (Physicist Harvey Brown) and the modern understanding of space-time.

You cannot formulate General Relativity using Poincare/Lorentz's conceptualization of relativity. You can, and Einstein did, using Einsteinian SR. Differences, for instance, in how one obtains the conservation of mass in GR vary widely depending on whether you use Einstein's approach or Poincare/Lorentz. I hope this settles the debate once and for all. Until his death, Poicare never fully grasped the full implications of what Einstein had done. Lorentz, a man Einstein called "the smartest man I have ever known," eventually came around to it once General Relativity proved so successful.

Answer (score 2):

An historical confection reposted from [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66075/the-half-life-of-a-theorem-or-arnolds-principle-at-work/66202#66202) … was young Albert Einstein a sci-fi reader? :)

---

I ran across the following (to me startling) example in Robert Cromie 1895 techno-thriller *The Crack of Doom* (reprinted in *The End of the World: Classic Tales of Apocalyptic Science Fiction*, Michael Kelehan, ed.)

> Page 102:  "If you consult a common text-book on the physics of the aether, you will find that one grain of matter, contains sufficient energy, if etherised,  to raise a hundred thousand tons nearly two miles."

Here "grain" is a standard unit of jewelers (one gram = 15.4 grains).  Then it is easy to verify, that within ±2% error, Cromie's "etherised" mass-energy relation is $E = m c^2/2$.

Einstein was 16 years old when Cromie's book appeared (published by a European publishing house) ... a *very* impressionable age, needless to say.  Yet despite the clue that Cromie so generously provided to science fiction fans in Europe, ten years passed before Einstein got the factor of two right! :)

Comment: This form of E=mc^2 was not due to Cromie, but it was standard lore that the field energy of the electron was comparable to the rest mass, and so people expected that E is a small constant times mc^2. Einstein showed that the coefficient is 1, he wasn't the first to suggest that there is a proportionality, but the unit coefficient is important, it makes relativity work. You can look at Tolver and DePretto for other E=mc^2 ideas floating at the end of the 19th century, to see where they come from, how different they are from Einstein's and why they fail.

Comment: @RonMaimon +1 for the references.